# How to install mysql to run as non-root

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have tried to install mysql, and then to run with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but I get

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I can get in with sudo, but I don't want to run as root. How do I get to run mysql as non-root?

I am using Linux Mint 19.1 32-bit.

What I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

- Set up VALIDATE PASSWORD? No
- Remove anonymous users? No
- Disallow root login remotely? Yes
- Remove test database and access to it? No
- Reload privilege tables now? Yes

Then I try

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it asks for the password, I give the same one I gave in mysql_secure_installation...

```
frank@frank-laptop:~/WebDev$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Gah.

I have reinstalled mysql client and server several times now, doing a complete uninstall between and getting rid of all databases when asked. I don't get asked for a root password during the install. That seems to be normal for an install in Ubuntu and derivatives, hence the mysql_secure_installation to set the password.

I tried following 
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMySQL.html
I tried searching on the web for hints, e.g.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/766900/mysql-doesnt-ask-for-root-password-when-installing#766908
and others but I have not been able to get mysql to start without sudo. If I do use sudo I can create a database, add tables and add data so the database is installed, I just need more privilege to run it than I think I should need.

Anywhere I looked, the instructions go from installation to starting mysql without anything special between, so I think I must be doing something quite stupid. But I have not been able to figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you run `mysql -u root -p` , you have to run it with `sudo` in order to create a new user:

```
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'XXX'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YYY';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'XXX'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then you can connect yourself using `mysql --user=XXX --password=YYY`

I already try but I don't think you can setup your DB without using `sudo` unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! I tried before the *.* edit, didn't get far. What does the '%' mean? I was trying with localhost, I'm sure that worked some years ago. Doesn't now. Now I followed your corrected instructions. After the GRANT succeeded, I quit mysql, and was able to connect with mysql -u root -p so it's looking good now :)

Comment: To clarify: using sudo to set up is ok, I was afraid I would have to do it always, which I think is not good.

Comment: Percent mean you allow remote connection

Comment: Ok, so it includes localhost? Cool! And localhost does still work, except I couldn't create create xxx@localhost because xxx@% had already been created. D'Oh! Dropped the existing user and created it with @localhost no problem (just to see if I could).

Comment: Yes, percent charactere include localhost, it means "all". For security it is better to not have percent but localhost.